# Using 'px' as a unit on inline SVGs in HTML

Tags: html, svg, width, inline-svg

Can I use `px` as a unit on inline svg images. For example using `width="100px"` and `height="100px"` in below example code is correct?

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid SVG. According to MDN, both the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height) attributes, are of type `<length>`, which is defined as follows:

> `length ::= number ("em" | "ex" | "px" | "in" | "cm" | "mm" | "pt" | "pc" | "%")?`

The length unit identifier is optional, but allowed in SVG attributes.